Is formating a number only to cast it to Double equivalent to rounding?
This expression is repeated multiple times in the codebase I am working with and I am just wondering if I am missing something here or if this is indeed just a strange way to round the number to three decimal places?
DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("##.###"); 

someDouble = Double.valueOf(DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(Double.valueOf(someString)));


The specific format cuts off at the 3rd decimal point. This could be intentional. Without knowing the use case, however, it is unclear whether it is necessary.

Minor correction: the expression does not cut-off, but round (it seems line) after the 3rd decimal point. ideone.com demo

Redudant was not the right word to use here. I was aware of the rounding effect but was wondering why one would just not use a rounding function? I edited my question.

This posts and its answers are of relevance here. I would go so far and say this question is a dupe.

There is hardly ever a good reason to reduce the precision of a floating point value unless you're presenting it as a final value in the presentation layer, at which point, it's a string

@Turing85 I do not see how that question is relevant. The number is not being formatted as a String, it is being converted to a Double.

The number is being converted from a String to a Double to a double to a String to a Double

"why one would just not use a rounding function?" - better ask one, we can only guess, and even harder not knowing anything about one

This is a somewhat problematic operation, but, yes, the intent is to round to 3 decimals. However, that isn't quite what ends up happening.
double rounding
Go grab a piece of paper. Write down the result of dividing 1 by 5 on this piece of paper, in decimal. You'll find you wrote "0.2". That was easy.
Now grab another piece of paper and write down 1 divided by 3.
Uhoh. If you managed, you're a deity. Because that is not possible: You'll have written a 0, a dot, and a lot of threes, but what you wrote down isn't quite correct.
The problem with computer math
Computers count in binary and not in decimal. Therein lies a very big problem.
The reason that '1 divided by 5' worked and '1 divided by 3' did not, is that 5 and 2 are divisors of 10. And no other numbers are. That means if you can rewrite the thing below the line (the denominator) such that it is simply a series of fives and twos, you'll be fine. I can ask you to write down '1 divided by 8' in decimal and it works out (0.125) because 8 is simply 2*2*2 and thus it's all twos and fives. You can do 20 (2*2*5): 1 / 20 = 0.05. You can't do 9, 7, 3, or even 30 (30 is 2*5*3 - that's a three, uhoh), and indeed 1/30 = .0333333333 with an endless sequence of threes.
Computers count in binary, and the only divisor is 2, then. In other words, in 'computer math', the only numbers that are exactly representable are e.g. 1/8, but.. it's just the powers of 2 as denominator, that's it. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etcetera. Not very many.
We can trivially prove this. Go run this code and marvel:
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(v == 1.0);

Look at that code. Guess what it prints. Run it.
Whaaaaaa???? - yes, that is false. This is the computer variant of me asking you to write out 1/3 on a piece of paper, then do that two more times, then I ask you to sum up the numbers on the 3 papers. You end up at 0.999999999999999. Which is almost, but not quite, 1.0. Hence, not equal to 1.0 - the computer did the same thing. Remember, a denominator of 10 factors down to 2*5 - that's acceptable in decimal, but doesn't work in binary (it has to be all 2s to work in binary).
How's that relevant to the question?
We humans think in decimal. But, the computer stores in binary. So, every time you write something as simple and innocuous as:
double v = 0.1;
System.out.println(v);

The computer is doing a ton of work - for starters, 0.1 is not a double. It simply isn't: For the same reason '1 divided by 3' is not a number you can write down on a piece of paper, 0.1 is not something the computer can store. So, the computer does a whole bunch of math to figure out the number that it can store that is as close to 0.1 as is imaginable. It's very close to 0.1. But not quite 0.1. It then stores this in binary.
Then, you ask it to print that convoluted number. Which it will, by.. converting that binary number to decimal and then printing that.
The point, then, is that 'rounding' is not a thing you can actually do - what does it even mean? Take, for example, the number "0.345". In fractions, that's 345/1000, which simplifies to 69/200 but that's where it ends, and 200 doesn't work - that's 2*2*2*5*5 which works in decimal (all fives and twos), but not in binary. So, even though 0.345 is nice and rounded to 3 decimals, in binary, that is not a thing, so the computer actually has to store 0.34499999999999999999999582561 or whatever it finds that is the nearest number that is representable in binary.
You're now praying that if you throw this number through whatever entity does math or shows it to users, that you 'luck out' and it remains 0.345 after rounding or whatever is applied to make it not look so silly.
Which usually works out.
Usually.
Generally, you don't ever want to round anything. Except at the very final moment, when you show a thing to a user. Round only then. So, using DecimalFormat is fine, but using this 'trick' to 'round' is just asking for bizarre errors down the line.
If you need precise math, use BigDecimal. It's slow, but, guaranteed accurate. And binary. It's so accurate, trying to ask it to divide 1 by 3 will simply cause an exception.
If you need precise rounding (say, you are representing euros and cents), store the atomic unit. You don't do:
double price = 45.99;

Instead you do:
long priceInCents = 4599;

Because long integers are perfectly accurate and round themselves, unless you go over a few quadrillion which, generally, you won't. They can't represent fractions of atomics (so no half-cents), but that's generally a good thing - banking systems can't either.

A most excellent Answer… except for the last clause of the last sentence. Banking systems do indeed track a fraction of the atomic currency unit such as fraction of a cent of a dollar or euro. For example, reading the fine print on a gasoline pump in the US will indicate that the advertised price of a gallon of gas at USD $ 4.87 is actually billed almost a cent higher, $ 4.879. A programmer must ask their project’s financial decision-makers as to what resolution to use in money math: whole cent, tenth of a cent, or sometimes even hundredth of a cent.

A select few systems do, but most don't. No banking transactional API out there will let you transfer half a cent. In general storing half-cents in your own system is [A] a massive headache (you still can't divide 1 by 3 no matter how much memory you give to BigDecimal, for example), [B] just kicks the can down the road. Okay, the system has carefully and with perfect accuracy determined that the balance of user lucy is 14.12948591 yen. Now what? You can't transfer that to her.

mil/mill. To support that, move the decimal point over yet another digit: long priceInMils = 45_990 ; // USD 45.99
